# MATLAB Yahoo Finance fetch gives a bizarre date format

Tags: matlab, yahoo-finance

Here's my chunk of code

```
y = yahoo;
% get some data for Apple
from = '2014-01-01';
to = '2016-04-01';
aapl = fetch(y,'AAPL','Adj Close', from, to);
close(y)
```

I get two columns - the second are the prices, the first are... Date values? But they cannot be! I expected Unix dates, but my dates start with `1455950` and a conversion gives me:

```
>> datetime(1455950, 'convertFrom', 'posixtime')

ans = 

   17-Jan-1970 20:25:50
```

So that clearly cannot be it. Also, what's crazy is if I get today's date, I get an even smaller value:

```
>> fetch(y, 'AAPL', 'Date')

ans = 

    Date: 736449
```

Can someone help me understand this madnesss?

Comment: Well the second result isn't crazy, `datestr(736449)` returns today's date.  What is the actual output of your query? Are all of the dates returned by your query that large?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, yahoo was simply giving out false values. All working now, and `datetime(x, 'convertfrom', 'datenum')` works perfectly as can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9hScQ8Vcrg).